# sys_refcursor from procedure not returning data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sys-refcursor

```
CREATE TYPE prList AS TABLE OF pr;

create or replace
procedure qLink(ret  out sys_refcursor)
 IS
myPrList prList := prList();


  open ret for
  select * 
  from (select a.lin, a.pr, 
               b.name, sum(a.up) as u,
               sum (a.d)         as d
          from li_dy_4 a,
               p_list  b,
               TABLE(CAST(myPrList as prList)) my_list
         where a.pr=b.id 
           and b.parent_id != 0 
           and a.partitionid <= 308 
           and a.partitionid >= 302 
           and a.pr = my_list.pr
         GROUP BY a.pr, b.name, a.lin  
         order by d desc) ;


BEGIN 

 myPrList := prList ( pr(91),
                   pr(80));


END;

  variable rc refcursor;
  exec qlink( :rc );
  print rc;
```

[/code]

The above sample code return no data,only table fields are displayed.what have I miss here?
but if didnt use the refcursor evry thing works fine even I tried passing array as a list it works with the above code,please help ...

Comment: Is your database Oracle?

Comment: There's something wrong with what you've posted; you have two `begin` and one `end`. You *appear* to be populating `myPrList` after you use it in the query, but it's a little hard to be sure with incomplete code?

Comment: sorry for the mistake...

Comment: @mohaskuar try making the variable ret as  `qLink(ret in out sys_refcursor)` also, put you open statement after the assignment of `myPrList` ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it must be like this:

```
create or replace
procedure qLink(ret  out sys_refcursor)
 IS
myPrList prList := prList();

BEGIN 

 myPrList := prList ( pr(91),pr(80));

  open ret for
  select * 
  from (select a.lin, a.pr, 
               b.name, sum(a.up) as u,
               sum (a.d)         as d
          from li_dy_4 a,
               p_list  b,
               TABLE(CAST(myPrList as prList)) my_list
         where a.pr=b.id 
           and b.parent_id != 0 
           and a.partitionid <= 308 
           and a.partitionid >= 302 
           and a.pr = my_list.pr
         GROUP BY a.pr, b.name, a.lin  
         order by d desc) ;

END;
```

And perhaps this `TABLE(CAST(myPrList as prList)) my_list` can be replaced simply by this one: `TABLE(prList(pr(91),pr(80))) my_list` - but I did not test it!

Comment: also I did not test it but that's not the way I would like,because at the end am going to change
     myPrList := prList ( pr(91),pr(80));
with an array as input.